# How can I store least used table files to a slower drive?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

Is it possible to separate the least used and most frequently used data files on to separate disks when using InnoDB?

Comment: Look in to partitioning for MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not really an automatic feature in MySQL 5.6, I could be wrong.

Notwithstanding, you can set it up manually.

Given the following information

- Your datadir is `/var/lib/mysql`
- You data is in the Database `mydb`
- You have this InnoDB table

Table Description

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
   if int not null autop_increment,
   ...
   primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

- You have a data folder to hold the least often used tables called `/data/least`
- Make sure `/data/least` is owned by `mysql`  by running `chown -R mysql:mysql /data/least`

Here is what you must do manually

```
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mytable_least
(
   if int not null autop_increment,
   ...
   primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DATA DIRECTORY='/data/least';
INSERT INTO mytable_least SELECT * FROM mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mytable_trash;
ALTER TABLE mytable_least RENAME mytable;
```

How was `mydb.mytable` manifested before the change ?

- The `.frm` file is `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- The `.ibd` file is `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd`

How is `mydb.mytable` now manifested ?

- The `.frm` file is `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- The `.ibd` file is `/data/least/mytable.ibd`

You should test this out with a blank InnoDB table and make sure.

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can separate tables into individual files and spread those files across different disks.  One example of documentation in MySQL (in this case for 5.7) is:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

A partial quote says: "This mode is controlled by the innodb_file_per_table configuration option, and is the default in MySQL 5.6.6 and higher."

Spreading the load can be useful for many applications.  (Using slower disks is really only for economic reasons of course.)